# Toggle a specific class with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm pretty new to jquery and I have this page with a bunch of collapsible accordions and I'm trying to toggle a glyphicon arrow up and down on the one accordion heading that I click on. The arrows are changing as planned, but all of them are changing, not just the one I'm clicking on.  I tried similar answers, but it just wouldn't work for my situation. I don't think I'm coding this right.

```
<div class="panel-heading menuBack" role="tab" id="headingOne">
  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
          Breakfast Burritos <span class="servicedrop glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>
      </h4>
  </a>
</div>

    $(this).click('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
      $('.servicedrop', this).toggleClass('glyphicon-upload');
    });
```

Comment: hi, here's the webpage I'm working on. It shows all the arrows change when I click on one menu. http://browncoder.com/primosmex/menu.html

Comment: In your context, it looks like `this` refers to the document itself. So clicking anywhere on the document will toggle all `.servicedrop` elements within the document.

Comment: Oh great, that makes sense. I'll have to clean this all up. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass 2 classnames to toggleClass and it will toggle between them as long as one is present on the element to begin with

```
$(this).find('.servicedrop').toggleClass('glyphicon-upload glyphicon-download');
```

Answer (score 0):

showdev helped me realize my $(this) refers to my whole document. Once I made the following changes, all went well.

```
$('.panel-title').click(function() {
  $('span', this).toggleClass('glyphicon-upload');
});
```